# Elementary matrix to produce row reduction operation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix below.

(a) Apply the elementary row operation R2 ← R2 − 3R1.
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1   \\
3 &  2   \\
0 &  3 
\end{pmatrix}
Which I think would become:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1   \\
0 &  -1   \\
0 &  3 
\end{pmatrix}

(b) Express the application of the row operation from part (a) as the multiplication of an elementary matrix with A.

This part I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your part (a) looks good.

The elementary matrix corresponding to this will be the identity matrix with a $-3$ in the $(2,1)$ entry since you're adding $-3$ times the first row to the second row. So the elementary matrix is $$E=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ -3&1&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ Then this corresponds to the row operation in $A$ by multiplying $$EA=\begin{bmatrix}1&1 \\ 0&-1 \\ 0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply two matrices, the rows of the result are linear combinations of the rows of the right-hand matrix, with the coefficients coming from the corresponding row of the left-hand matrix.

Here, the first and third rows of the given matrix are unchanged, so the elementary matrix will have the form $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ *&*&* \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The second row of the result is supposed to be $R_2-3R_1$, from which we can read that the second row of the elementary matrix must be $(-3,1,0)$.

One way to see why this is the case is to write the right-hand matrix of the matrix product $AB$ in block form, so that it looks like you’re multiplying a vector by a matrix: $$A\begin{bmatrix}B_1\\B_2\\\vdots\\B_n\end{bmatrix}.$$ The $i$th row of the product is then formally just the dot product of the $i$th row of $A$ with this vector: $a_{i1}B_1+a_{i2}B_2+\dots+a_{in}B_n$, a linear combination of the rows of $B$.